# What's a good adjective or phrase to describe your feeling when confronted with absurdity?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases, expressions, idioms

Say, you're supposed to be very angry at something but the situation is SO ABSURD that it becomes funny and you end up laughing at it instead. It cannot be having  mixed or ambivalent feelings about it since you're definitely not happy about the situation but its absurdity makes it so bloody hilarious.  So how are you feeling?

Comment: Not exactly the conventional definition of slaphappy ;-)

Comment: Actually, it is one of the ways of controlling and managing anger. For example, this sentence is from [a publication about anger from Nebraska University](http://www.ianrpubs.unl.edu/pages/publicationD.jsp?publicationId=937): "Laugh at yourself. When you feel angry, take your annoyances to a ridiculous extreme until you laugh at their absurdity. Laughter not only banishes negative emotions, it’s relaxing."

Answer (score 1):

If you are feeling the anger and the [hilarity](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/hilarity) simultaneously, you actually **are** feeling

[***ambivalent***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/ambivalent)

> ADJECTIVE
>
> Having ***mixed*** feelings or ***contradictory*** ideas about
>   something or someone:

The [*strength*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=ambivalence&allowed_in_frame=0) of your anger, and the *strength* of your amusement are *both* at play in your mind:

> "simultaneous conflicting feelings," 1924 (1912 as ambivalency),
>
> from German Ambivalenz, coined 1910 by Swiss psychologist Eugen
>   Bleuler (1857-1939) on model of German Equivalenz "equivalence," etc.,
>
> from Latin *ambi*- "**both**" (see ambi-) + *valentia* "**strength**,"
>
> from present participle of valere "be strong" (see valiant).
>
> A psychological term that by 1929 had taken on a broader literary and
>   general sense.

Usually the *ambivalence* is between the strength of [**love** and **hate**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Love%E2%80%93hate_relationship) (anger), rather than anger and hilarity.

The [etymology](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=absurdity&allowed_in_frame=0) of [absurdity](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/absurd) intersects at *incongruity* and *dissonance* of your emotional experience:

> late 15c., from Middle French absurdité,
>
> from Late Latin absurditatem (nominative absurditas) "**dissonance**,
>   **incongruity**," noun of state
>
> from Latin absurdus "out of tune;"
>
> figuratively "incongruous, silly, senseless,"
>
> from ab-, intensive prefix, + surdus "dull, deaf, mute" (see
>   susurration).

You're so mad you shouldn't be laughing, but you are!

Answer (score 0):

You could say that you became ***hysterical***.

It used to mean: Insane - due to overwhelming emotions. (Brought on by female complications, supposedly)

Although it's usually used nowadays in AmE to refer to something funny, it still has the meaning of "laughing because of uncontrollable emotions."

Comment: Whoops! I forgot to mention that the laughter is not necessarily vocal - it can be inward. Hysterical is definitely not the right term.

Answer (score 0):

You chose not to get angry and saw it as a ***tragicomic*** situation.